# How to simulate two computers connected with LAN when you have only one computer?

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming

I wish to test a networking application between two computers connected by `LAN`.

These computers will have different IP addresses.

I have only one computer.

How to simulate two computers connected with `LAN` and having different IP addresses when I have only one computer?

> **Platform**: Linux.
>
> **Language**: C

Comment: First option I would think of is running two virtual machines on your computer.

Comment: @Chiel92 - one is sufficient. Then you've an actual machine and a virtual machine. Total - 2 IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends what you want to test. If you don't care about some low level TCP nuances I think you don't need to go into virtualization as other suggest here.

Note that socket is identified by port number, protocol (TCP vs UDP) AND the network interface.
When you bind a socket you can specify on which particular network interface it should listen. But if you don't specify it (which is usually the case) the socket is bound to all interfaces on given port.
So it should be enough to have two network interfaces on your computer - for example one on your LAN card and the other on a WLAN card, or simply the loopback interface (`localhost` aka `127.0.0.1`) Note that you have a different IP on each of these interfaces. 
You just need to make sure that you bind your sockets to specific IPs. Each instance of your program binds to a different IP.

Let's suppose your IP on the LAN network card is `192.168.1.101`. You could use the following code to listen on this particular interface only:

```
/* ... */
int ssocket;
struct sockaddr_in address;

bzero((char *)&address, sizeof(address));
address.sin_family=AF_INET;
address.sin_port=htons(12345);
inet_aton("192.168.1.101", &address.sin_addr.s_addr);
ssocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(ssocket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
/* ... and so on ... */
```

Note that this code will listen on `192.168.1.101:12345`, but not on `127.0.0.1:123456`. You can make listening IP address configurable in your application. Then simply use localhost for one instance and LAN addresses for the other instance of your application.

I'm pretty sure you could also create a virtual network interface on linux, but I haven't ever done it so you would need to google for that on your own.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like [Graphical Network Simulator](http://www.gns3.net/) may be useful.